# What happened to StackExchange a short while ago? Why had it gone down?

Tags: discussion

No StackExchange site was accessible a short while ago. Even [isitdownrightnow](http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/stackoverflow.com.html) said it was unreachable. See there ping results (16.Feb.2014 10:51   0 ms.)

What had gone wrong?

Comment: Every major website has downtime. If you look up terms like "six 9's" etc , you get an idea

Comment: ok, in this case - a DDoS attack

Comment: Stack Exchange just needed to have a little nap.

Comment: Well nothing to worry about, it was just an heart attack! Doctors say the site would recover but we should not mention this alot :/ Should we? ...

Comment: OK in this case, 3 9's or 4 9's is SO's grade - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_availability

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan - hehe , in this case it's OK . a DDoS is like an online hurricane